# bitcoind is not working

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

```
 curl --user ryunishida:password --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", 
 "id":"curltest", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-
 type: 
  text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:18332/ -w '%{http_code}\n'
```

---

`bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` below

```
 rpcuser=ryunishida
 rpcpassword=password

 HOST=localhost
 server=1
 txindex=1
 rpcport=18332
 testnet=3
```

then i get 401

Comment: You mean `.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`, right?

Comment: Yes I meant that